# Extra \endgroup. \begin{document} Frustrations

Tags: compilation-error

*UPDATE 27/02/2022:
Question has been answered. See Comments below. Thank you everyone for your help.*

Same issue as quite a few here. Booted up my LaTex project after a few months hiatus and ... it doesn't work anymore. LaTex is so infuriating that way.

Anyway, it's been a few days and I can't track down where this damn `Extra \endgroup. \begin{document}` error is coming from.
I've pasted by `\listfiles` log below.

```
*File List*
    book.cls    2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
    bk10.clo    2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
   babel.sty    2022/02/13 3.71 The Babel package
 bblopts.cfg    2005/09/08 v0.1 add Arabic and Farsi to "declared" options of b
abel
 english.ldf    2017/06/06 v3.3r English support from the babel system
geometry.sty    2020/01/02 v5.9 Page Geometry
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
  ifvtex.sty    2019/10/25 v1.7 ifvtex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
   iftex.sty    2022/02/03 v1.0f TeX engine tests
geometry.cfg
csquotes.sty    2021-02-22 v5.2l context-sensitive quotations (JAW)
etoolbox.sty    2020/10/05 v2.5k e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
csquotes.def    2021-02-22 v5.2l csquotes generic definitions (JAW)
csquotes.cfg    
biblatex.sty    2022/02/02 v3.17 programmable bibliographies (PK/MW)
pdftexcmds.sty    2020-06-27 v0.33 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2020-05-10 v1.25 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2020-10-07 v3.14 Key value format for package options (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2019/12/15 v1.18 Key value parser (HO)
  logreq.sty    2010/08/04 v1.0 xml request logger
  logreq.def    2010/08/04 v1.0 logreq spec v1.0
  ifthen.sty    2020/11/24 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
     url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
  blx-dm.def    2022/02/02 v3.17 biblatex localization (PK/MW)
blx-unicode.def
blx-compat.def    2022/02/02 v3.17 biblatex compatibility (PK/MW)
biblatex.def    2022/02/02 v3.17 biblatex compatibility (PK/MW)
standard.bbx    2022/02/02 v3.17 biblatex bibliography style (PK/MW)
 numeric.bbx    2022/02/02 v3.17 biblatex bibliography style (PK/MW)
 numeric.cbx    2022/02/02 v3.17 biblatex citation style (PK/MW)
biblatex.cfg    
   expl3.sty    2022-02-05 L3 programming layer (loader) 
l3backend-xetex.def    2022-02-07 L3 backend support: XeTeX
blx-case-expl3.sty    2022/02/02 v3.17 expl3 case changing code for biblatex
  xparse.sty    2022-01-12 L3 Experimental document command parser
mathpazo.sty    2020/03/25 PSNFSS-v9.3 Palatino w/ Pazo Math (D.Puga, WaS) 
 tocloft.sty    2017/08/31 v2.3i parameterised ToC, etc., typesetting
appendix.sty    2020/02/08 v1.2c extra appendix facilities
  xcolor.sty    2021/10/31 v2.13 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
   xetex.def    2021/03/18 v5.0k Graphics/color driver for xetex
colortbl.sty    2020/01/04 v1.0e Color table columns (DPC)
   array.sty    2021/10/04 v2.5f Tabular extension package (FMi)
multirow.sty    2021/03/15 v2.8 Span multiple rows of a table
 eso-pic.sty    2020/10/14 v3.0a eso-pic (RN)
epigraph.sty    2020/01/02 v1.5e typesetting epigraphs
nextpage.sty    2009/09/03 v1.1a additional page commands
 caption.sty    2020/10/26 v3.5g Customizing captions (AR)
caption3.sty    2020/10/21 v2.2e caption3 kernel (AR)
pdfpages.sty    2022/01/29 v0.5u Insert pages of external PDF documents (AM)
    calc.sty    2017/05/25 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
graphicx.sty    2021/09/16 v1.2d Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty    2021/03/04 v1.4d Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    2021/08/11 v1.11 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
 ppxetex.def    2022/01/29 v0.5u Pdfpages driver for XeTeX (AM)
 ltablex.sty    2014/08/13 v1.1 Modified tabularx
longtable.sty    2021-09-01 v4.17 Multi-page Table package (DPC)
tabularx.sty    2020/01/15 v2.11c `tabularx' package (DPC)
nicefrac.sty    1998/08/04 v0.9b Nice fractions
  attrib.sty    2001/08/31 v1.3 attribution of block elements (Frankenstein's h
at)
moredefs.sty    2001/08/31 v1.8 more defining commands (Frankenstein's brain)
lettrine.sty    2020-03-14 v2.23 (Daniel Flipo)
  minifp.sty    2013/12/30 v0.96. Macros for real number operations and a stack
-based programing language.
lettrine.cfg
booktabs.sty    2020/01/12 v1.61803398 Publication quality tables
 siunitx.sty    2022-02-15 v3.0.49 A comprehensive (SI) units package
translations.sty    2022/02/05 v1.12 internationalization of LaTeX2e packages (
CN)
 amstext.sty    2021/08/26 v2.01 AMS text
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
l3keys2e.sty    2022-01-12 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys
enumitem.sty    2019/06/20 v3.9 Customized lists
 quoting.sty    2014/01/28 v0.1c Consolidated environment for displayed text
scrextend.sty    2021/11/13 v3.35 KOMA-Script package (extend other classes wit
h features of KOMA-Script classes)
scrkbase.sty    2021/11/13 v3.35 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-dependent bas
ics and keyval usage)
 scrbase.sty    2021/11/13 v3.35 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-independent b
asics and keyval usage)
scrlfile.sty    2021/11/13 v3.35 KOMA-Script package (file load hooks)
scrlfile-hook.sty    2021/11/13 v3.35 KOMA-Script package (using LaTeX hooks)
 scrlogo.sty    2021/11/13 v3.35 KOMA-Script package (logo)
threeparttable.sty    2003/06/13  v 3.0
 relsize.sty    2013/03/29 ver 4.1
threeparttablex.sty    2013/07/23 v0.3 by daleif
 environ.sty    2014/05/04 v0.3 A new way to define environments
trimspaces.sty    2009/09/17 v1.1 Trim spaces around a token list
textcomp.sty    2020/02/02 v2.0n Standard LaTeX package
titlesec.sty    2021/07/05 v2.14 Sectioning titles
  forest.sty    2017/07/14 v2.1.5 Drawing (linguistic) trees
    tikz.sty    2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
     pgf.sty    2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
  pgfrcs.sty    2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
pgfrcs.code.tex
 pgfcore.sty    2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
  pgfsys.sty    2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
pgfcore.code.tex
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
  pgffor.sty    2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
 pgfkeys.sty    
pgfkeys.code.tex
 pgfmath.sty    
pgfmath.code.tex
pgffor.code.tex
tikz.code.tex
 pgfopts.sty    2014/07/10 v2.1a LaTeX package options with pgfkeys
elocalloc.sty    2016/12/15 v0.03 local allocation for LaTeX 2015+ (DPC)
inlinedef.sty    2008/07/10 v1.0 Inlined expansions within definitions
forest-lib-linguistics.sty    2017/07/14 v0.1.2
forest-lib-edges.sty    2016/12/05 v0.1.1
 titling.sty    2009/09/04 v2.1d maketitle typesetting
fancyhdr.sty    2021/01/28 v4.0.1 Extensive control of page headers and footers

fontspec.sty    2022/01/15 v2.8a Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
fontspec-xetex.sty    2022/01/15 v2.8a Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
 fontenc.sty
fontspec.cfg
chngcntr.sty    2018/04/09 v1.1a change counter resetting
afterpage.sty    2014/10/28 v1.08 After-Page Package (DPC)
footmisc.sty    2022/02/14 v6.0b a miscellany of footnote facilities
multitoc.sty    1999/06/08 v2.01 MultiToc Package (MS)
multicol.sty    2021/10/28 v1.9b multicolumn formatting (FMi)
imakeidx.sty    2016/10/15 v1.3e Package for typesetting indices in a synchrono
us mode
 xkeyval.sty    2020/11/20 v2.8 package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
 ifxetex.sty    2019/10/25 v0.7 ifxetex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
ifluatex.sty    2019/10/25 v1.5 ifluatex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
idxlayout.sty    2012/03/30 v0.4d Configurable index layout
hyperref.sty    2021-06-07 v7.00m Hypertext links for LaTeX
kvdefinekeys.sty    2019-12-19 v1.6 Define keys (HO)
pdfescape.sty    2019/12/09 v1.15 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
 hycolor.sty    2020-01-27 v1.10 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
letltxmacro.sty    2019/12/03 v1.6 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
 auxhook.sty    2019-12-17 v1.6 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
  pd1enc.def    2021-06-07 v7.00m Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
hyperref-langpatches.def    2021-06-07 v7.00m Hyperref: patches for babel langu
ages
 intcalc.sty    2019/12/15 v1.3 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2019/12/15 v1.7 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
   puenc.def    2021-06-07 v7.00m Hyperref: PDF Unicode definition (HO)
  bitset.sty    2019/12/09 v1.3 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
bigintcalc.sty    2019/12/15 v1.5 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
atbegshi-ltx.sty    2021/01/10 v1.0c Emulation of the original atbegshi
package with kernel methods
  hxetex.def    2021-06-07 v7.00m Hyperref driver for XeTeX
stringenc.sty    2019/11/29 v1.12 Convert strings between diff. encodings (HO)
rerunfilecheck.sty    2019/12/05 v1.9 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
atveryend-ltx.sty    2020/08/19 v1.0a Emulation of the original atveryend packa
ge
with kernel methods
uniquecounter.sty    2019/12/15 v1.4 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
bookmark.sty    2020-11-06 v1.29 PDF bookmarks (HO)
bkm-dvipdfm.def    2020-11-06 v1.29 bookmark driver for dvipdfm (HO)
xwatermark.sty    2011/10/22 v 0.96: framed or shaded text with page breaks
catoptions.sty    2014/08/29 v0.2.7h Securing catcodes and parsing options (AM)

  fix-cm.sty    2020/11/24 v1.1t fixes to LaTeX
  ts1enc.def    2001/06/05 v3.0e (jk/car/fm) Standard LaTeX file
 picture.sty    2020-04-22 v1.6 Dimens for picture macros (HO)
 ltxkeys.sty    2012/11/17 v0.0.3c A robust key-value parser (AM) (Ahmed Musa)
  framed.sty    2011/10/22 v 0.96: framed or shaded text with page breaks
ESB_HARDBACK_ALEX.xwm
ragged2e.sty    2021/12/15 v3.1 ragged2e Package
 english.lbx    2022/02/02 v3.17 biblatex localization (PK/MW)
ltcaption.sty    2020/05/30 v1.4b longtable captions (AR)
pdflscape.sty    2019/12/05 v0.12 Display of landscape pages in PDF (HO)
  lscape.sty    2020/05/28 v3.02 Landscape Pages (DPC)
translations-basic-dictionary-english.trsl    (english translation file `transl
ations-basic-dictionary')
 nameref.sty    2021-04-02 v2.47 Cross-referencing by name of section
refcount.sty    2019/12/15 v3.6 Data extraction from label references (HO)
gettitlestring.sty    2019/12/15 v1.6 Cleanup title references (HO)
ESB_Title_Black_and_White.pdf    Graphic file (type pdf)
 ot1pplx.fd    2004/09/06 font definitions for OT1/pplx.
 omlzplm.fd    2002/09/08 Fontinst v1.914 font definitions for OML/zplm.
 omszplm.fd    2002/09/08 Fontinst v1.914 font definitions for OMS/zplm.
 omxzplm.fd    2002/09/08 Fontinst v1.914 font definitions for OMX/zplm.
 ot1zplm.fd    2002/09/08 Fontinst v1.914 font definitions for OT1/zplm.
Chapter_02.tex
TKML_ESB_Part_Circuit_Board_01.pdf    Graphic file (type pdf)
chapterHead_10cm.pdf    Graphic file (type pdf)
chapterHead_10cm.pdf    Graphic file (type pdf)
chapterHead_10cm.pdf    Graphic file (type pdf)
chapterHead_10cm.pdf    Graphic file (type pdf)
Appendix.tex
chapterHead_10cm.pdf    Graphic file (type pdf)
chapterHead_10cm.pdf    Graphic file (type pdf)
chapterHead_10cm.pdf    Graphic file (type pdf)
ESB_HARDBACK_ALEX.ind
chapterHead_10cm.pdf    Graphic file (type pdf)
 ***********
```

Comment: Well take that as a trigger to cleanup your preamble a bit. But beside this: don't load xwatermark, it uses the catoptions package which is incompatible with a current latex.

Comment: Thank you for confirming that xwatermark is an issue -- am currently looking into it. However, I don't see what I can do as regards "cleaning my preamble": although dense, it seems to me that everything in it is being used. Moreover, before the update, everything worked.
This actually might confirm that xwatermark is the culprit !

Comment: well xwatermark is certainly the culprit. And if you have a good overview over your preamble then why weren't you able to identify the problematic package yourself? You only need to add a minimal body and then comment the package one by one.  The error is at begin document, so it must be due to something in the preamble.

Comment: Ulrike, thank you. I understand "clean your preamble" now, as it indeed was xwatermark.

Comment: @CyanideBaby please note that `xwatermark` was always problematic (because of its `catoptions` dependency) and was incompatible to LaTeX for a while. There were just "recent" (as in a year ago, iirc) change to the LaTeX kernel which made the thing finally break with an error message instead of breaking things silently.

Comment: Thank you for this. Clarifies to me that I've been away from LaTex for at least a year. Time flies. All's well now though. Project works well again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package `xwatermark` is of the same author as `catoptions` and is built upon the latter package.

Unfortunately, even having repeatedly been advised that doing low level changes to kernel commands is not good policy, because new releases of LaTeX might break those changes, the author ignored the advice.

Recent updates to the LaTeX kernel have indeed broken `catoptions`. Packages using it no longer work. Don't use them.